# How to generate ov2 poi programmatically from csv source

Tags: python, csv, point-of-interest, transform

I'm looking at how to generate an ov2 file programmatically. Mainly I use python and I found something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11796824/generating-a-ov2-file-with-java). But that kinda vague. I can't find documentation on how the file is build up. Also it looks like a binary file and is hard to reverse engineer.

How to generate a ov2 file programmatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a good description of the file format that matches the post you've linked:

https://gordthompson.github.io/ov2optimizer/ov2FileFormat.html

Since it's a fairly simple format it's just a matter of using [`struct`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html) to go back and forth to binary

```py
import struct

STATUS_DELETED = 0
STATUS_REGULAR = 2


def to_ov2(lon, lat, label, status=STATUS_REGULAR):
    size = 14 + len(label)
    lon = int(lon * 100000)
    lat = int(lat * 100000)
    label = label.encode('utf8')
    buff = struct.pack(f'<B3i{len(label) + 1}s', status, size, lon, lat, label)
    return buff


def from_ov2(buff):
    status, size, lon, lat, label = struct.unpack(f'<B3i{len(buff) - 14}sx', buff)
    lon /= 100000
    lat /= 100000
    label = label.decode()
    return lon, lat, label, status


if __name__ == '__main__':
    buff = to_ov2(77.0365, 38.8977, "Party location")
    print(buff)
    lon, lat, label, status = from_ov2(buff)
    print(lon, lat, label, status)
```

However I don't have any software/device to test with, so I can't guarantee that's 100% correct.

Comment: He @mikewatt this is definitely the right course. When I write this to a file it looks 99% like the already existing ov2 file. It won't load when I use an tool like "PoiEdit". It seems like there are 2 minor differences that cause the problem. Jet I don't understand binary that much. For example: if we look to the start of a record in hex: 02 43 (original file) 02 42 (python generated). And this seems to be consistent: 02 3B (original file) 02 3A (python generated). Secondly it seems the string is terminated with two nulls. We're very close to the solution. Now I'm trying to figure it out.

Comment: Oké the length was off. I changed 13 into 14, and now it works! Maybe you could update your answer with that minor detail. Thanks @mikewatt!

Comment: Good catch, edited.  I wasn't totally sure what was considered part of the record when calculating the record length, the whole thing or everything after that point.  Apparently it's the former

Comment: After some debugging I found out that the encoding should not be in `utf-8` but in `raw_unicode_escape`. I now use `label.encode('raw_unicode_escape')` and `label.decode('raw_unicode_escape')`.